# function to delete a node from linked list at nth position giving segmentation fault

Tags: c, linked-list

```
void deleteat(int pos)
{
    struct node *temp,*temp1;
    //temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp1=temp=head;
    int i;
    if(pos==0)
    {
        temp=head->next;
        free(head);
        head=temp;
    }
    else
    {

        for(i=0;i<pos;i++)
        {   
            temp1=temp;
            temp=temp->next;
        }    
        temp1->next=temp->next;
        temp->next=NULL;
        free(temp);

    }
}
// Fucntion calls in the main
deleteat(4);
deleteat(1);
deleteat(6);
```

I submitted a similar code on an online judge, but it got accepted there, while running the same code on my linux machine gives the segmentation fault (core dumped). I know this question has been asked many times, but I couldn't find the error in my code.

Comment: Have you tried clicking "Debug"

Comment: I am writing this code on gedit. How shall I use debug there? Sorry, relatively new to linux.

Comment: Why don't you post *all* the relevant code? What is `head`?

Comment: Learn about [GDB: The GNU Project Debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

Comment: As for your problem, why don't you check that `head` isn't `NULL`? Or when you iterate over the list, you have no check that you're not going beyond the end of the list. Do you have any validation or checks at all?

Comment: @EOF , The entire code is a bit long, since I am practicing basic linked list operations. Here's the code https://ideone.com/nRQInV .

Comment: You need to learn about GDB - when you get a chance Eclipse + CDT is really helpful

Comment: Okay. Thanks @AlecTeal .

Comment: I'm totally serious. Gedit.... it's literally like Notepad++ (they have the same highlighting engine) and it's better than no syntax highlighting at all, but IDEs are DESIGNED to help you do this stuff. They understand the code. Also I'm a ctrl+space wh0r3. Seriously.

Comment: Why do `temp->next=NULL;` just before you free `temp`? It seems useless.

Comment: Just to be on a safer side, avoid a dangling pointer.

Comment: At else part you must handle the last node separately, because tail node has no next node and temp gonna access it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you iterating list you don't check if temp or temp1 are valid pointers. Some of them could be null

Comment: Using debugger helped, I could resolve my error, and the error was in a line   where temp and temp1 had to be valid pointers. Thanks!